# Error in with mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem in sql

The SQL Error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '58.47 €'')' at line 1

The sql code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ponudba 
(ime_ponudbe,zaporedna_stevilka,id_podjetja,veljavnost,znesek) VALUES('$ime_ponudbe','$zaporedna_stevilka','$id_podjetja','$veljavnost,'$znesek'')");
zaporedna_stevilka -> value 1
id_podjetja -> value 2
veljavnost -> value 17.11.2010
znesek-> value is 58.47
```

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ponudba (ime_ponudbe,zaporedna_stevilka,id_podjetja,veljavnost,znesek) VALUES('$ime_ponudbe','$zaporedna_stevilka','$id_podjetja','$veljavnost,'$znesek')");
```

You have an extra ' (apostrophe) at the end of the last variable.

Answer (score 1):

If your table field `znesek` is double, make sure `$znesek` is double too, looks like it's string.

Comment: +1 If `znesek` is number (int ot other numeric type) then error is while `$znesek` value actually is '58.47 €' (string).

Answer (score 0):

Change '$znesek'' to '$znesek'. You have used a double quote. Should be a single quote.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using now? Does it match Ergo's above?

Comment: It's not a double quote, he has two single qoutes instead of one.

Comment: Your code (below) is correct as far as I can see. Make sure that the format of the data you are putting into the database matches the format expected especially date fields.

Comment: I.e. $znesek is not a number...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$podjetje = $_POST['podjetje'];
        $veljavnost = $_POST['datepicker'];
        $naziv_artikla_storitve = $_POST['naziv_artikla_storitve'];
        $kolicina = $_POST['kolicina_st'];
        $storitev_em = $_POST['em_ime'];
        $cena_st = $_POST['cena_st'];
        $cena_popust = $_POST['cena_popust'];
        $cena_s_popustom = $_POST['cena_s_popustom'];
        $vrednost_st = $_POST['vrednost_st'];
        $znesek = $_POST['znesek'];
        $popust_na_vse = $_POST['popust_na_vse'];
        $z_z_popustom = $_POST['z_z_popustom'];
        $ddv = $_POST['ddv'];
        $koncni_znesek = $_POST['koncni_znesek'];
        $datum = date("d.m.Y");

        $preveri_zap_stevilko = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT max(zaporedna_stevilka) as zaporedna_stevilka FROM ponudba"));
        $stevilka = $preveri_zap_stevilko['zaporedna_stevilka'];

        $preveri_st = mysql_query("SELECT zaporedna_stevilka FROM ponudba ORDER BY zaporedna_stevilka ASC");

        $i=1;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($preveri_st))
        {
            if($i != $row['zaporedna_stevilka'])
            {
                $manjkajoca_stevilka = $i;
                break;
            }
            $i++;
        }

        $vel = sizeof($manjkajoca_stevilka);
        if($vel == 0)
        {
            $zaporedna_stevilka = $stevilka+1;  
        }
        else
        {
            $zaporedna_stevilka = $manjkajoca_stevilka; 
        }

        $dobi_id_podjetja = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stranka WHERE ime_podjetja='$podjetje'"));
        $id_podjetja = $dobi_id_podjetja['id'];

        $arr = str_split($zaporedna_stevilka);

        $vel =  sizeof($arr);

        if($vel == 1)
        {
            $nova_st = "0000".$zaporedna_stevilka;  
        }
        if($vel == 2)
        {
            $nova_st = "000".$zaporedna_stevilka;   
        }
        if($vel == 3)
        {
            $nova_st = "00".$zaporedna_stevilka;
        }
        if($vel == 4)
        {
            $nova_st = "0".$zaporedna_stevilka;
        }
        if($vel == 5)
        {
            $nova_st = $zaporedna_stevilka; 
        }
        $ime_ponudbe = "P-".$nova_st."-".$datum;

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO ponudba (ime_ponudbe,zaporedna_stevilka,id_podjetja,veljavnost,znesek) VALUES('$ime_ponudbe','$zaporedna_stevilka','$id_podjetja','$veljavnost,'$znesek')");
```

?>

Comment: You should be editing your question, not adding an answer...

Comment: You can re-edit your original post to add this.  You are now missing a single-quote in your query: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO ponudba (ime_ponudbe,zaporedna_stevilka,id_podjetja,veljavnost,znesek) VALUES('$ime_ponudbe','$zaporedna_stevilka','$id_podjetja','$veljavnost','$znesek')");`

Answer (score 0):

What character set is the mysql table?  Is '€' valid? As others mentioned, the last quote mark is wrong.  Also, more dangerously, this code smells bad of SQL Injection vulnerability.  Please research placeholders to handle your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

A few recommendations:

Enclose all field names between ` characters

Where you are referencing variables/values, replace:

`'$variable'` with `'".mysql_real_escape_string ($variable)."'`